# Nature of Permissions - Copy Fails on my Own Files

Tags: permissions, copy

I am trying to copy some files from one (Journalled HFS+) volume to another, on my own (multi-boot) computer.

I can not drag and drop the files, so... it is not my main question, but I wonder if someone could explain why not -- or, more to the point, how to do this, if it is possible, please?

My main question has to do with permissions.

When I use the work-around of right-clicking and doing a "Copy To", I get the following error message.

> > The folder [source folder] cannot be handled because you do not have permissions to read it.

[Emphasising:  source]

I understand that Unix is very careful with permissions, and there are reasons why it might not let me copy files from one place to another.  Nonetheless, I can not imagine why I can not copy files from one of my own folders, into another, on my own machine.

The sticking point for me is that, when I search for information on how to do such a copy, all the answers involve changing the permissions of the files.  Now, it seems to me that, if the permissions are some particular thing such that they have to be changed, then the corollary is that they really should be left as they were, for the purposes of the system they came from.  So...

- (If I follow said instructions) am I changing the permissions of the files *just from a local point of view* , or actually changing *the* permissions of the files, such that they might not work in the system they came from?
- Is there some way -- analogous to logging in as administrator in Windows -- that would allow me to just have the authority to just-copy-the-files-thank-you-very-much?

... please?

> > Update

On the basis of comments (notably Melebius's), I have just tried a different source folder, and now I get a different error message -- "The folder [source folder] cannot be copied because you do not have permissions to create it in the destination."  That is... it does not complain about the source.

I take it, then, that there actually *is* something anomalous about the original source folder.  I am not yet sure what to make of that, but it really highlights my main desire/need, being... to get Unix to *just do the stupid copy*, thank you very much.  (I would do it in Windows, which is much more reasonable, except that Microsoft thought, "Who could possibly ever need a path longer than 256 characters?"; you would think they would have learnt *that* lesson.)

I take it that there is no flag for a copy command that will ignore permissions (?).  [Like sudo.]

I take it there can be only one owner of an item?

!  Can I give myself full read-write-whatever permission, in *addition to* whatever is set for the item, without making myself the owner... please?  (And would this work?)

> > Quasi-Answer

I take it that, theoretically, [there *is an answer* to my question!! {emoticon for jumping around in uncontrollable happiness}, and it is…] the answer to my question is that one simply logs in as root.  That is, there is a login account “root”, that has absolute power.

[ Later:  I am thinking that this works only because the owner of the files is the same — Root… that, even logged in as Root, one could still not do anything to files whose owner was, for instance, System; I do not actually know. ]

Thus, for instance, to do something with a directory… you can give yourself ownership of a directory using “sudo chown {yourUsername} {directoryPath}”… or you can just do whatsoever you might want to the directory, as root, without any hinderances.

I forgot to check just now, but the last time I looked no one had mentioned this.  There is a reason for this:  when you are logged in as root, the computer takes you to be an ultimate Linux hacker, and will let you do whatever you want without a murmur.  (You still can not do things like writing to a volume that is read-only.)

If you are game, there are instructions here.  [I hope this is okay.]
https://www.wikihow.com/Become-Root-in-Linux
(I liked it better without the large pictures.)

There is a further reason, I am thinking, being that in the normal course of using a computer… if you can not access something there is a good reason for it [not that *that* is always true].  However, in my case — fooling around with files from another computer — that principle fails to apply.

To tentatively answer my other question:  it *looks to me as though* the permissions I am seeing are the actual permissions from the other machine, directly taken as permissions for the Linux machine I am using (as opposed to Linux having permissions of its own, applied as defaults to files from a foreign computer with an alien permission system).  Of course, that is because the other computer system is (also) Unix-based; the permissions system is not alien in the slightest.  [Actually, Unix can probably understand a variety of alien permissions systems, I would guess.]

BTW:  (My impression is that) if you try to do something in the GUI, and it simply ignores it… if you do the same thing using a command-line command, it will give you an error message, which apparently is beyond the GUI.  I am taking it that that is why I could not drag-and-drop the files, and did not get an error message either.

Comment: Why would you be using HFS+ fs on Ubuntu?  Is this Ubuntu you are using?  Apple is off-topic here.

Comment: Could you give an example of where you've found advice to change permissions and exactly what the instructions are?  I would have thought you needed to [adjust the *mount* options](https://superuser.com/a/365270/596513). I don't think you would be able to change file permissions unless the partition was mounted with write access (and I'm not sure it would be possible even then, but presumably HFS+ filesystems support the same permission settings as Linux filesystems)

Comment: I Googled "ubuntu copy permissions on my own machine" (which is not to imply that that is ideal) and, broadly speaking, clicked on links with "permissions" in their titles.

Comment: Sorry, Zanna; is the point that... I need to unmount the target volume and re-mount it with a switch "-o", for journalling to be okay?  (... Over and above the problem with the source.)

Comment: Is the HFS+ you are copying to _Journaled_ (like default Mac filesystem)? If so, Ubuntu is not able to write to it. Permissions aren’t the main problem here, drivers are.

Comment: @Melebius|  Yes, journalled [edited question].  I do not know either way, but, according to the link Zanna gives [post by mivk], you can?  ...  This still leaves the noted issue, which is about reading the source; I should (barring Unix objecting) be able to use an NTFS target (?).  ...  Is it implied that there is no problem with *reading* HFS+_J, please?

Comment: Well, if you install additional drivers (`hfsprogs`), it might work. However, I haven’t tried yet, I’ve been able to work with the Mac partition only accessible as read-only from my Ubuntu (rather than to risk destroying the Mac partition).

Comment: @Carsogrin Please do not put the answer as a part of the question, use the answer field below. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Melebius:  Can I do that for an answer to *part* of the question, please?  (I guess that would imply that I should have asked two separate questions.)